# Adobe Acrobat / Microsoft Outlook - Placing a <hr> or similar in a mailto link

Tags: pdf, outlook, acrobat, mailto

Currently I have:

```
mailto:email@example.com?subject=Test Subject &body=Paragraph One. %0A%0A <hr/> %0A%0AParagraph Two. %0A%0AParagraph Three. %0A%0AParagraph Four.
```

And the hr code isn't working because it is in the body and it is reading it as plain-text. Any way to get a hr working in the mailto or anything similar? Would love to break up paragraph one from the rest of the body if possible. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do that. Mailto only works with plain text body, no HTML.

Comment: Looking for a work around. For example:

in Outlook you can achieve multiple different hr's by entering 3 special characters and hitting enter, ie: --- + enter gives you a basic hr. However adding:

    ---%0A%0A

seems to only produce "---".

Comment: Have you tried %0B? 0xB is a soft line break in Word (equivalent to <br>).

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry - it didn't work as intended but I appreciate the extra information, still showing "---" when using "---%0B". I will accept your answer that this is impossible until someone can prove otherwise. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Hmmm... Actually the following worked perfectly for me: mailto:user@domain.demo&body=line1%0Bline2 - I just typed it in the address bar in IE.

Comment: %0B works fine for a line break - but my workaround by using "---" followed by that line break did not work to create a <hr> as say just typing "---" and hitting enter does.